# Angular/Typescript Google Login API with ux_mode: redirect

Tags: angular, google-api

The issues that I have is when I use google sign in method with popup window the resolve is finished and Im getting the user from the google api but when I use ux_mode: 'redirect' option for sign in method after sign in I cant resolve the user. I tried to connect on https but still not working, also I've registered the redirect URI to the google console. Here is the code that I'm using.

```
initClient() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
    gapi.client
      .init({
        clientId: 'some client id',
        discoveryDocs: 'discovery',
        scope: 'some scope',
      })
      .then(
        () => {
          gapi.client.setApiKey('key');
          resolve();
        }
      );
  });
});
```

}

```
login() {
this.initClient().then(() => {
    gapi.auth2
      .getAuthInstance()
      .signIn({
        ux_mode: 'redirect'  //with redirect mode doesn't resolve user
      })
      .then(
        (user) => {
            user.getBasicProfile(),
            user.getAuthResponse()
            // put user on backend
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I found is that google redirect is not returning promise. It returns and url with the information about the login. I've solved this with accessing it with with window.location.has and got the info from it.

```
const hash = window.location.hash ? window.location.hash.split('#') : [];
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Except my url doesn't have the access_token only the id_token. Does your url have an access_token?